# What permisions to I need to fix a DnsPermission exception?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I am writing a SQL CLR trigger, which, among other things, opens a TCP socket connection to another computer to send some data. The call to `new TcpClient(hostname, port)` fails with the error

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

What SQL Server (2012, in this case) and/or Windows Server (2012 R2) permission change do I need to ask the DBA to make, in order for my CLR code to work?

Comment: [EXTERNAL_ACCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/security/clr-integration-code-access-security)

Comment: @AlexK. feel free to add as an answer